# What is the meaning and use of this file "reportWebVitals.js" in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Out of curiosity and finding ways to understand how reactjs works. I want to know the use of this file in a react boilerplate app. I am new to react.

```js
const reportWebVitals = onPerfEntry => {
  if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
    import('web-vitals').then(({ getCLS, getFID, getFCP, getLCP, getTTFB }) => {
      getCLS(onPerfEntry);
      getFID(onPerfEntry);
      getFCP(onPerfEntry);
      getLCP(onPerfEntry);
      getTTFB(onPerfEntry);
    });
  }
};

export default reportWebVitals;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `reportWebVitals` function, you can send any of the results to an analytics *endpoint* to measure and track real user performance on your site.

For more information and examples visit the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/measuring-performance/#:%7E:text=reportWebVitals) here.